# OSGi framework for arm-linux board

Tags: linux, arm, osgi, equinox, jamvm

I have arm 9 board running linux.
I have ported Jamvm and its working fine.
Now I need to port OSGi framework on top of it.

I am new to OSGI.

Kindly help me with the procedure/tutorial on how to port osgi on arm-linux.

I prefer Equinox or Flex frameworks.

Kindly suggest if any other framework is available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No porting should be required since Equinox and Felix are both written in pure Java. Of these two, Felix is more lightweight.

Also look at Knopflerfish, which is another open-source OSGi implementation that is often used in embedded programming.

You might also want to look at ProSyst mBedded Server, which is a commercial product.